# How do I get the download button to register the link provided as a url?

Tags: python, tkinter, youtube-api

Beginner coder, first time using TKinter.
when I click the Download button, the code doesn't execute as I'd expect (I expect it to download the video). Of the errors that are raised, one is a RegexMatchError and I think the problem is in this line "yt = YouTube(f"{url}")">
any assistance will be appreciated.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
from pytube import YouTube

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x200")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title("Youtube Downloader")

tk.Label(root, text="Hello :)\nWelcome to Youtube Downloader.\n").pack()

url = tk.StringVar()

# Link frame
link = ttk.Frame(root)
link.pack(padx=10, pady=10, fill='x', expand=True)

# Link
link_label = ttk.Label(link, text="Enter the Youtube link:\n")
link_label.pack(fill='x', expand=True)

link_entry = ttk.Entry(link, textvariable=url)
link_entry.pack(fill='x', expand=True)
link_entry.focus()


# download button
def download_clicked():
    print("Welcome to Youtube Downloader.")
    showinfo(
        title='Information',
        message='Download has began!'
    )
    yt = YouTube(f"{url}")
    stream = yt.streams.get_by_itag(22)
    size = round(stream.filesize / 10 ** 6, 2)

    print(f"Downloading {yt.title}, \n Length: {yt.length} seconds, \n Size: {size} MBs")


download_button = ttk.Button(
    root,
    text='Download',
    compound=tk.LEFT,
    command=download_clicked
)

download_button.pack(ipadx=5, ipady=5, expand=True)

# Exit button
exit_button = ttk.Button(
    root,
    text='Exit',
    command=lambda: root.quit()
)

exit_button.pack(
    ipadx=5,
    ipady=5,
    expand=True,
    side="left"
)

try:
    from ctypes import windll

    windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)
finally:
    root.mainloop()
```

the error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\hp\Desktop\git\YoutubeDownloader\tkinter yt dowloader.py", line 36, in download_clicked
    yt = YouTube(f"{url}")
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.video_id = extract.video_id(url)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 133, in video_id
    return regex_search(r"(?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).*", url, group=1)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube\helpers.py", line 129, in regex_search
    raise RegexMatchError(caller="regex_search", pattern=pattern)        
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: regex_search: could not find match for (?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).*
```

Comment: Please show as exactly which error you are getting. Not just a description of it. Having the exact error at hands is extremely helpful when trying to answer a question.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please checkout the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
yt = YouTube(f"{url}")
```

to:

```
 yt = YouTube(f"{url.get()}")
```